# keras.layers.Dense not assigning correct names for layers. Instead getting "module_wrapper_x" names for each layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
import logging

# I create my model here:
tf.random.set_seed(1234)  
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.Input(shape=(2,)),
        Dense(3, activation='sigmoid', name = 'layer1'),
        Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name = 'layer2')
     ]
)
model.summary()
```

**Once I run the model summary, I get the following result:**

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 module_wrapper (ModuleWrap  (None, 3)                 9         
 per)                                                            
                                                                 
 module_wrapper_1 (ModuleWr  (None, 1)                 4         
 apper)                                                          
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 13 (52.00 Byte)
Trainable params: 13 (52.00 Byte)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
```

**What I was expecting to get is:**

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 layer1 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 9         
                                                                 
 layer2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 4         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 13
Trainable params: 13
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

So, it's not saving my layers names for some reason that I don't understand, and its giving weird "module_wrapper_xyz" names instead.

**What am I doing wrong with the naming's?**

**How Is it not assigning the names correctly to each layer?**

My dependencies are (if necessary):

```
tensorflow = {version = "^2.13.0" }
python = ">=3.10,<3.12"
matplotlib = "^3.6.3"
keras = "^2.11.0"
jupyterlab = "^3.5.3"
scikit-learn = "^1.2.1"
numpy = "^1.26.0"
jupyter = "^1.0.0"
```

Comment: Never import from `tensorflow.python`, just use `tensorflow.keras.layers`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xdurch0 is right. Just import without `.python` as bellow and you will get the correct layer names.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```